# Audio input in Microsoft Surface?

Tags: pixelsense

The official data sheet of Microsoft Surface says that there is no audio input available:

```
Audio
• Output type: Stereo fl at panel built-in speakers
• Output compliant standards: Stereo
• Input: None
```

Is this really true? I think I have seen applications that can be controlled by voice recognition. So how can this be done?

And if it is not available in Surface 1.0 will it be available in Surface 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For auio input on Surface, people generally plug in USB microphones.  No word on if that changes in 2.0 but I would doubt it.